# xp_cmdshell SQL Server 2012: How to create a text file with "< , >" characters in it?

Tags: sql-server, shell, cmd

I'm trying to create a txt file in a shared folder using `xp_cmdshell` in SQL Server.

The code works perfectly, but I need to begin the text with:

```
"<0600 ..."
```

So when I write `" < "` or `" > "` in the query, I get an error:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Here's an example of my code:

```
declare @Text as nvarchar(150)  declare @Cmd as nvarchar(100)  set    @Text = '<0600 /SERIAL= ....>'  set @Cmd ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > C:\Test.txt'  execute ..xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

So, how can I create the text file with these characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the redirection symbols (`<` and `>`) with `^`

```
declare @Text as nvarchar(150)  
declare @Cmd  as nvarchar(100)  

set @Text = '^<0600 /SERIAL= ....^>'  
set @Cmd  ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > C:\Test.txt'  

execute ..xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php